# Laravel 10 how to Prevent Default Eager Loading in Nested Laravel Eloquent Relationships with withOnly()?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with Laravel 10 and I'm encountering an issue regarding the [default eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-by-default) functionality of Eloquent relationships. In my case, I have a model where I am using withOnly() to specifically avoid the default eager loading. However, when I access a relationship `rel` of this model, all the default eager loads defined in `rel` are still being loaded. This also applies to nested relationships like `rel.rel2`.

Here's the code I am using:

```
Model::withOnly(['rel']);
```

I'm having trouble understanding how to apply withOnly() on these relationships to prevent default eager loading. Could anyone guide me on how to apply this method to nested relationships in Laravel 10 to avoid default eager loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not tested but try:

```php
Model::withOnly(['rel' => fn($query) => $query->withOnly('rel-to-be-loaded')]);
```